# Show days a week even though there's no data from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a time management schedule. The table is like this:

```
Days    | Start | End
Monday  | 08:00 | 11:00
Tuesday | 07:00 | 12:00
...
```

I want to keep showing days from `Monday` to `Sunday` even though in database there's no data for it.

I want the result to be like this:

```
Days    | Start | End   |
Monday  | 08:00 | 11:00 |
Tuesday | 07:00 | 12:00 |
...
Sunday  |   -   |   -   |  // if there's no sunday data in database it still 
                           // showing sunday but the start & end is empty
```

There's also a chance where the results of query is null, so it will end up error because I don't have any value inside variable when using foreach later in views.

This is my controller:

```
$work_hours = AttendanceGroupWorkHour::where('attendance_group_id', $id)->get();
```

And this is my view:

```
@foreach ($work_hours as $work_hour)
  <tr>
     <td> 
        {{ $work_hour->days)
     </td>
     <td>
        {{ $work_hour->start)
     </td>
     <td>
         {{ $work_hour->end)
      </td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
@endforeach
```

Sorry but I really don't have any idea how to do it. Any help would be helpful for me.

Comment: can you share the database table?

Comment: if there is no data in DB you want to show the days from Monday to Sunday with empty values? You only want to show 1 week at a time?

Comment: @B.Grgr `Days | Start | End` the database is like this

Comment: @BernardWiesner yes I only want to show 1 week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over `$work_hours`, which might be missing days that you want to display, iterate over the days of the week (or dates between your start/end, whatever you are doing).  As a demonstration let's just iterate over this week.

In your Controller:

```
// First step is to make your $work_hours addressable.  Use keyBy()
// so that we can do something like $work_hours['Monday'].
$work_hours = AttendanceGroupWorkHour::where('attendance_group_id', $id)
    ->get()
    ->keyBy('days');

// Now let's build an array of every day this week - you would have
// to adjust this to match the dates in $work_hours.
$days = [];
$start = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
$end = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
for ($day = $start->copy(); $day->lte($end); $day->addDay()) {
    $days[] = $day->format('l'); // Eg "Monday"
}

// Now pass the full set of days to the view, along with your "data" days:
return view('some.view', [
    'days'       => $days,
    'work_hours' => $work_hours
]);
```

Now in your view:

```
@foreach ($days as $day)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $day }}</td>
        <td>@if (isset($work_hours[$day]) {{ $work_hours[$day]->start }} @endif</td>
        <td>@if (isset($work_hours[$day]) {{ $work_hours[$day]->end }} @endif</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Anyway, what if I also want to get `id` from `$work_hours` for each data?

Comment: `$work_hours[$day]->id`? If you want to see what your `$work_hours` looks like, try `dd($work_hours);`.

Comment: oh I see... I just need to call it like that. thanks for your help, it's working

Answer (score 1):

I like to keep logic in backend as much as possible. I didnt test it but this should work, and you can use your same view implementation.

```
$workDays = AttendanceGroupWorkHour::where('attendance_group_id', $id)->get()->keyBy('days'); //make sure only 1 week is returned Monday to Sunday, would be better to add to your query a where clause
$daysOfWeek = ['Monday' => 0, 'Tuesday' => 1, 'Wednesday' => 2, 'Thursday' => 3, 'Friday' => 4, 'Saturday' => 5, 'Sunday' => 6];
$scheduledDays = [];

foreach($daysOfWeek as $dayOfWeek => $value){
    if(!isset($workDays[$dayOfWeek])){
        $scheduledDays[] = ['days' => $dayOfWeek, 'start' => '-', 'end' => '-'];
        continue;
    }
    $scheduledDays[] = ['days' => $workDays[$dayOfWeek]->days, 'start' => $workDays[$dayOfWeek]->start, 'end' => $workDays[$dayOfWeek]->end];
}
return view('your.view', [
    'scheduledDays' => $scheduledDays
]);
```